# Using Arial font for just one page and Mathpazo for rest

Tags: fonts, mathpazo

I'm writing a document using `Memoir` documentclass that requires just one page of the text to be in `Arial` font and for this I'm using the following code:

```
 \usepackage{helvet}
 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

For the rest I'd like to use mathpazo, so I've loaded the mathpazo package (with small capitals support). When I use the code above the entire document gets the `Arial` font, so how can I restore back or change the font to `Mathpazo`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

Palatino: \blindtext
\newpage

\begingroup
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
Helvetica (Arial): \blindtext
\endgroup
\newpage

Palatino: \blindtext

\end{document}
```

The second page is in Helvetica, called Arial by Microsoft